# change laravel default composer command

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

this might be a little awkward but I am using two different versions of composer named (composer `v2.3`, composer2 `v2.2`)

and also using two different versions of PHP (PHP8.1, PHP7.2)

I am using Windows and Environment Variables are set.

now when I want to run an old Laravel project by this command `php72 artisan serve`, it uses the newer composer version, which does not support PHP7.2 and artisan fails!

so my question is, Is there any way to tell artisan to use `composer2` instead of the default `composer` command??

Comment: I am not sure if there is a way, but the "best" solution would be to use `Docker` (or [Laravel Sail](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sail)). The whole idea of `Docker` is to have an isolated environment where you can have WHATEVER you want, in your case 2 environments, one with `PHP 8.1` and `Composer 2.3`, and another environment with `PHP 7.2` and `Composer 2.2`. That would fix your issue and make your life way way easier